# Check if current page is taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms

How can I check if the current page is a taxonomy term page, similarly to what done with the following code used to check if the current page is the front page?

```
if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
  // The current page is the front page.
}
else {
  // It is not the front page.
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just to offer a solution that doesn't make use of `arg()` (which it's advised to avoid where possible according to the [docs page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7))

You can use the [`menu_get_object()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) function:

```
$term = menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2);
if ($term) {
  // User is on a taxonomy term page
}
```

Comment: I guess above code also get executed in taxonomy/term/id/edit & feed pages too !! We may need to check for third argument ?

Comment: @AnilSagar Holy moly you're right :P I'm really not sure what the accepted way to do this is then, assuming I haven't made up that bit about `arg()` being less readable

Comment: How about popping a little `&& !path_is_admin(current_path())` in the `if` statement?  I've not checked it yet, but term edit paths are admin pages, no :)

Comment: Also - `arg()` being hard to read reference is [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7).

Comment: @Chapabu Hah, didn't think to check the docs page :P Yeah the `path_is_admin()` method should do the trick, good call. I just tried it and it returns true for the taxonomy edit page so short of a module implementing `hook_admin_paths` and removing it that method should be pretty reliable

Comment: This answer has now the Chapabu seal of approval :)

Comment: @Chapabu You should trademark that ;)

Comment: @Chapabu Just thought actually, `path_is_admin()` would fail for the `taxonomy/term/x/feed` URLs so I think there might be a better method out there

Comment: Might be obvious for many, but for everyone else I'd like to point out that minor readability concerns should not be a reason to sacrifice the quality of your functionality. If using arg() is important for you and there's nothing better at hand then avoiding it would be wrong. The function exists since at least Drupal 5 and seems to be moving into version 8 for good reasons.

Comment: Caution: Enabling Views replaces the taxonomy term loader, causing menu_get_object('taxonomy_term', 2); to not work anymore. See: https://drupal.org/node/1468006 and https://api.drupal.org/comment/45018#comment-45018

Comment: @Manu Good find. I would expect that behaviour though; after all, if you enable the replacement for the core taxonomy page it stands to reason that the load function would also be changed

Comment: @Clive Yep, but sadly does replace the term loader ever if you don't use the Views taxonomy term page replacement..

Comment: @Manu Are you sure? I mean I'll take your word for it as I don't have time to check, but it feels like I would've run into that before at some point and it doesn't ring a bell. If true that's definitely a bug in the views module IMO

Comment: @Clive, just experimented few days ago, and had to fall back to the arg() way... See _merlinofchaos_ [comment](https://drupal.org/node/1236840#comment-4820598) about this behavior. (It was on D6, but still valid on D7). More precisely does not replace the term loader but [alters routing system](https://api.drupal.org/comment/45018#comment-45018).

Answer (score 5):

`<?php if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && arg(2)): ?>` should do the trick.

In case edit/feed (and possibly some other related pages) should be excluded you can use:
`<?php if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && arg(2) && !arg(3)): ?>`

Comment: That will also return true for `taxonomy/term/123/edit` which I'm not sure the OP wants.

Comment: Yeah he didn't say what he is aiming for precisely, but I've updated my answer to address that concern.

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php

if (arg(0) ==  "taxonomy" && arg(1) == "term" && is_numeric(arg(2)) && arg(3) == "") {
  // Taxonomy term page
}

?>
```